# gitlab-runner - accept jobs only at certain times?

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Is there a way to configure a `gitlab-runner` (13.6.0) to accept jobs only between certain times of the day?

For example - I would like to kick off a 'deployment' pipeline with test, build and deploy stages at any time of the day, and the test and build stages can start immediately, but I would like the final deploy stage to happen only between, say, midnight and 2am.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

GitLab Documentation describes how to [use cron to trigger nightly pipelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/triggers/README.html#using-cron-to-trigger-nightly-pipelines%22). Additionally, there is a `$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE` predefined environment variable that can be used to limit the jobs that run in a pipeline.

Using these 2 features it shall be possible to run the same pipeline in 2 different ways. The "normal" runs will be only for test/build Jobs. The "nightly" runs triggered by cron will be only for deploy job that has to check the `$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE` value.

Let me know if this option fits your environment.